# Карта(google maps) как background к сайту и/или отрицательный z-index помогите разобраться!

Tags: z-index, html, css

Здравствуйте господа, такая проблемка:

- Нужно гугл мепс (или другие карты) как бэкграунд к сайту;
- На них сверху объекты: шапка, текстовые колонки, футер;

Так вот между объектами есть паддинги\маргины и тд и такое ощущение будто над картами висит прозрачный див и не дает управлять ими, сорри незнаю как ещё объяснить...

Вот набрасал грубый пример: http://jsfiddle.net/s3jWs/

Вместо карт там див с текстом, так вот как сделать чтобы получить к нему доступ? (стало возможность выделять, копировать текст в тех местах где не покрывают другие дивы с индексом выше)?

Comment: так http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s3jWs/2/ ?

Comment: вы просто применили везде position: absolute?

Comment: есть еще pointer-events: none; но почему-то в вашем примере не заработал.